# Show checkboxes in two columns in WooCommerce Product Add-Ons

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm using WooCommerce Product Add-Ons to show toppings for a pizza as checkboxes. Out of the box it shows all the checkboxes in one long list, making the page very long.

[image]

I would like to show the checkboxes in two columns. Could anyone help with the right CSS?

I've searched and found the following code:

```css
.checkbox{
    width:49%;
    display: inline-block;
}
label {
    display: block;
}
```

You can find the staging site on: https://dev.justsay.nl/. To show the checkboxes, scroll to pizza, and click on the + of one of the pizza's.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this

```
.wc-restaurant-product-modal .wc-pao-addon > p {
display: inline-block;
width: 45%;
```

}